# Pink ocean on android when trying to render Crest3D oceans in unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, arcore

I am making an android application using ARCore in unity3D. I tried adding ocean to it with Crest3D (https://github.com/wave-harmonic/crest). I got everything to work on my macbook, but when I open my app on my phone, the ocean is pink. I think this is a shader error, but I am inexperienced.

I know ARCore is not the problem because I rendered a cube just fine.

Everything compiles and runs, and the only errors (warnings) I get are:

```
Shader warning in 'FFTSpectrum': HLSLcc: The resource '_ResultDisplaceX' uses an unsupported type/format at kernel SpectrumUpdate (on gles3)

Shader warning in 'FFTSpectrum': HLSLcc: The resource '_ResultDisplaceZ' uses an unsupported type/format at kernel SpectrumUpdate (on gles3)

Shader warning in 'FFTSpectrum': HLSLcc: The resource '_ResultHeight' uses an unsupported type/format at kernel SpectrumUpdate (on gles3)

Shader warning in 'FFTCompute': HLSLcc: The resource '_Output1' uses an unsupported type/format at kernel ComputeFFT (on gles3)

Shader warning in 'FFTCompute': HLSLcc: The resource '_Output2' uses an unsupported type/format at kernel ComputeFFT (on gles3)

Shader warning in 'FFTCompute': HLSLcc: The resource '_Output3' uses an unsupported type/format at kernel ComputeFFT (on gles3)
```

In unity I am using: Gles3, ARCore 4.2.7, and Unity 2021.3.22f1
My phone is: Google Pixel 6A, Android 13

I was expecting to see an ocean
I tried debugging to the best of my ability

(I am ok with not using Crest3D, I just need to render an ocean in AR)